# What sort of bike chain do I need for my bike?

Tags: road-bike, chain, repair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tell which size chain my bike uses?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3062/how-can-i-tell-which-size-chain-my-bike-uses)

I have a vintage Ross road bike, and the chain recently snapped during one of my rides.
The bike has 2 gears in the front and 5 in the back. Making that a 10 speed bike?
What affordable bike chain can I buy to replace the snapped one? And should I be looking at 10 speed chains? Or would a 9 speed suffice?

Comment: I think [this question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3062/how-can-i-tell-which-size-chain-my-bike-uses) probably provides the answer.