# Which chain should I use for Rex Touring with 5 gears?

Tags: chain

The bike is about 15 years old. The size of tyre is probably 28.

I want to change the old chain.
I am not sure which chain I can put to the bike.

**Does any chain which length is enough for 28 fit my bike?**

Comment: Post more information: picture ideal, description of gears better. Does it have derailleur? In that case 3/32. If it is not using derailleur then 1/4 inch. To get the length right, compare to existing chain.

Comment: Chain *length* isn't particularly vital -- most chains will come with extra length and you use a chain tool to shorten it to the correct length. This is why so many wrenchers have key-chain fobs made of bits of leftover chain.

Comment: @Mathew, I suggest putting that as an answer, as I tried to come up with an answer that says much more and failed. Maybe say "BMX/singlespeed chain" as well as 1/8" (I assume 1/4 was a typo :)

Comment: First one needs to know if this is a derailleur bike or one with a multi-speed hub.  Most likely 3/32" (internal width) for derailleur (this would be called a "5-speed chain") or 1/8" (internal width) for the multi-speed hub (this would be a "fixed gear" chain).

Comment: My first thought is that, if this bike has a front derailer, it'd use the same size chains the old 10-speeds used. But aside from that, I've got nothin'. An interesting question.

Comment: Masi: look [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3062/how-can-i-tell-which-size-chain-my-bike-uses) and this [answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/heavier-thicker-chains-and-gears-for-winter-due-to-salt/2721#2721).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question, no, any chain which is long enough is not compatible with your bike. No one here can tell you what chain will fit without a lot more detail in your question, but [this](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_ch.html) is a good place to start. [Daniel](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/1584/daniel-r-hicks) posted that link as a comment on my earlier answer.

Ask your LBS. They will know once they see the bike. Or measure the width of the outside chain plates with a vernier caliper on the old chain.